# Sort out Bubble with Jquery Effect

Tags: jquery

I want to magnify all bubble one by one once are loaded to initial size.

My JS fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/ASPZm/

I want to show hover effect automatic once all bubbles are loaded with effect.

My tried code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var i = 20;
$('.box').animate({
    width: '30px',
    opacity: '1',
    height: '30px',
    marginLeft: '-15px',
    marginTop: '-15px'
}, 2000);

$('.box').each(function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            marginLeft: '-105px',
            marginTop: '-105px',
            fontSize: '40px',
            opacity: '1',
        }, 200).addClass('sachin').find("strong").css("display", "block");
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: '30px',
            height: '30px',
            marginLeft: '-15px',
            marginTop: '-15px',
            fontSize: '20px',
        }, 300).removeClass('sachin').find("strong").css("display", "none");
    }, 400 * i);
});

$('.box').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        marginLeft: '-105px',
        marginTop: '-105px',
        fontSize: '40px',
        opacity: '1',
    }, 300).addClass('sachin').find("strong").css("display", "block");
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: '30px',
        height: '30px',
        marginLeft: '-15px',
        marginTop: '-15px',
        fontSize: '20px',
    }, 300).removeClass('sachin').find("strong").css("display", "none");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger `mouseover` event by calling:

```
$(".box").trigger("mouseover");
```

After all the handlers are applied.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/ASPZm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

.animate() has a callback function which is executed after the animation is complete. You can pull all the hover functionality into a separate function, and then you can call the new function in the .animate() callback.